# How to match alphabetic name and number in solr?

Tags: solr

I am newbie to solr. Can anybody tell me how to match alphabetic name and number (Ex : one and 1)in solr?
Any clue is highly appreciated. Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to add all of these to the synonyms, but of course you would only do that for 1 to 20 maybe...